Window Function Not Allowed Here
This is my query:
Sum(
    Get_Business_Days( 
        LAG(CREATED_DT,1) OVER (PARTITION BY OPERATION_ID ORDER BY OPERATION_ID, CREATED_DT, ACTIVITY_ID),
        CREATED_DT )
) OVER (MARCS_OPERATION_ID, CREATED_DT, ACTIVITY_ID)

FROM DATASOURCE

WHERE 
    CREATED_DT BETWEEN 
          @Prompt('Enter Start Date','DT',,Mono,Free,Persistent,,User:1) 
      AND @Prompt('Enter End Date','DT',,Mono,Free,Persistent,,User:2) 
ORDER BY (PARTITION BY OPERATION_ID ORDER BY OPERATION_ID, CREATED_DT, ACTIVITY_ID)

I am getting an error:

Window function not allowed

What am I missing?
The @Prompt gets user input on execution. Get_Business_Days is a defined function that uses two dates.
This SQL works fine if I remove the Sum, but I need to aggregate the counts of days.

you can't nest a window function (lag) inside another aggregate (sum). nest your query in another query block and do the sum there.

Please restore SELECT keyword. It's easier this way.

You cannot nest one analytic function inside another analytic function. You need to use an inline view (also called a sub-query) or a sub-query factoring clause (also called a CTE):
SELECT SUM(business_days)
         OVER (MARCS_OPERATION_ID, CREATED_DT, ACTIVITY_ID)
FROM   (
  SELECT MARCS_OPERATION_ID,
         CREATED_DT,
         ACTIVITY_ID,
         Get_Business_Days( 
           LAG(CREATED_DT,1) OVER (
             PARTITION BY OPERATION_ID
             ORDER BY OPERATION_ID, CREATED_DT, ACTIVITY_ID
           ),
           CREATED_DT
         ) AS business_days
  FROM   DATASOURCE
  WHERE  CREATED_DT
           BETWEEN @Prompt('Enter Start Date','DT',,Mono,Free,Persistent,,User:1)
           AND     @Prompt('Enter End Date','DT',,Mono,Free,Persistent,,User:2) 
)

